# Activity setContent() to another layout file

Tags: android

I have activity_main which is default layout in my activity, there i have framelayout which display fragment whit different layout, is it possible to connect the different layout textview to setText() from my activity? How to connect from activity to this fragment xml layout?

```
activity_main
   frameLayout
      fragment 1 xml
      fragment 2 xml
   /frameLayout
```

Activit.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dirShow("a");
}


void dirShow(String s) {
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment1);
    textPath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.path_text);
    textPath.setText(s);
}
```

Comment: Tell the View responsible to change itself?

Comment: Without seeing a fair bit more code, it's hard to say...

Comment: We need more information about what you're trying to do. Usually if you're calling `setContentView` after `onCreate` it's a great signal that you probably want to be starting a new Activity displaying a new Fragment's UI, or otherwise using a more structured method of switching views instead.

Comment: update code, i have activity and fragment whit diffrend .xml layouts, i need to change fragment layout from activity. Activity layout have FrameLayout which display fragment layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling setContentView more than once in an activity. The content view is the entire activity layout. If you want to change the layout the proper way to do it is to change the fragment or activity, and have the new activity or fragment show the new layout.

If you're not trying to change layouts, then just put the TextView you need in the first layout that you set. Posting your layout files and telling us what you're trying to do may allow us to help you achieve what you want.

EDIT:
If I understand your updated question correctly, you're using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). If that's the case, call the dirShow() function in the Fragments onCreateView() function instead of the activity's onCreate() function.

If you're just incorrectly using the term fragment in your question, I suggest you switch to using them.

Comment: I just need to connect to textview in diffrent layout file, which is not set in whit contentview(). Is this possible?

Comment: My question is why is your TextView in a different layout file? If you want to show the TextView dynamically you can set its visibility to GONE and then set it to VISIBLE. Or you can place a ViewStub where you want it and inflate it when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You want to include another xml into your main xml usin include tag, and set text on textview as you want.